# Vertically align container with fixed position and dynamic height to middle of viewport?

Tags: dynamic, height, alignment, center, fixed

How do I align a container (eg social media plugins) with **fixed position** and **dynamic height** so that the container itself is vertically in the middle of the viewport? The container itself is visible as I have a background image and some border effects. The content inside the container should be vertically aligned as well.

This is what I have but it doesn't work, the container doesn't even show up for some reason:

```
#socialpluginscontainer {
position:fixed;
width:100px;
height:70%;
padding-left:5px;
right:10px;
background: transparent url(../pictures/pagecontentoverlay.png);
-moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #000 inset;
-webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #000 inset;
box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #000 inset;
}
#socialplugins {
text-align:center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="socialpluginscontainer">

      <div id="socialplugins">

           //code for social plugins

      </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

to align container vertically in center you can do so.

```
#socialpluginscontainer {
    position:fixed;
    width:100px;
    height:70%;
    padding-left:5px;
    right:10px;

    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;

    background: tomato;
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #000 inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #000 inset;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #000 inset;
}
```

for content look the  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dmrv3jym/)